# Which postgresql package should I use?

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I'd like to access an existing postgres database, which is on my local (mac) machine, from haskell.

I can see quite a few postgres packages on hackage. Which is likely to be the easiest for me to use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[postgresql-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple), a binding to libpq, was [just announced](http://blog.melding-monads.com/2011/12/30/announcing-postgresql-simple/), and seems to have a nice feature set. I haven't used it myself (or indeed PostgreSQL from Haskell at all), but it [seems to have community support](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/nw5dn/announcing_postgresqlsimple/), so I'd recommend it if you don't want to use a particular library on top (like HDBC or persistent).

The alternatives appear to be [libpq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/libpq) (another binding to libpq), which postgre-simple is based on, and [pgsql-simple](https://github.com/chrisdone/pgsql-simple) (a direct implementation of the wire protocol in Haskell), which, going by the post, doesn't seem ready for prime-time yet, and is not on Hackage.

There is also a [PostgreSQL driver for HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-postgresql); the [PostgreSQL backend](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-postgresql) for the [persistent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent) library (as used in Yesod) is based on it.

Answer (score 8):

Opaleye is a higher-level alternative to `postgresql-simple`.  It uses `postgresql-simple` under the hood but provides a typesafe and composable API.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye